# Can aquafaba be used in place of flax egg as a binding agent?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, vegan, chickpeas, flax

I'm interested in following a recipe for lentil wellington.  The recipe uses "flax egg", a mixture of ground flax and water, as a binding agent for the lentil and vegetable loaf.

My preferred "egg substitute" is aquafaba (the water chickpeas are cooked in) since it is already a by-product of making chickpeas, and it has a pleasant flavor which makes it a useful ingredient on its own.  I already have 3 jars of it of different concentrations sitting in my fridge. Ground flax is not something I have and might not be able find at a normal grocery store.

I'd just prefer to go with the thing I have.

But I'm not sure if I can make this substitution. Aquafaba is by no means a perfect all around egg substitute.  I've used it to make meringues, in pancakes and as an egg wash but this is using it as a binding agent.  And this specific recipe uses canned chickpeas *drained* meaning that the instructions basically tell you to just throw out aquafaba.  If it were a viable substitute here I might expect them to use it.

How does aquafaba compare to flax egg when used as a binding agent for making a loaf?  If making this substitution should one use a high concentration (very viscous) or low concentration (less viscous) aquafaba?